# Blender how to deselect surfaces

Tags: blender, blender-2.61

My case is after adding a plain, I subdivided it into several surfaces. Then I pressed B, and selected, say, 4 of the surfaces. However, how to deselect one of the 4 selected surfaces?
I am totally new to blender, any help is appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: This question if off-topic as not programming related. You better ask that kind of questions at blender.stackexchange.com. But anyway - hold shift and either right-click on points you want to remove, or use B with shift pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold shift and right click on the face you wish to deselect.